# Symfony component cache boxes

Tags: php, caching, symfony-1.4

I try to cache some components and partials in my symfony project.

I set `cache.yml` for caching and turned on cache for dev environment in `settings.yml`. When I refresh my website the cache boxes are blue but I think they should be yellow [as the doc says](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_2/en/12-Caching):

> if boxes are yellow the partial is taken from cache

My caching is not working. Does anybody know why it happen?

Comment: Does a new refresh display yellow box or still blue one?

Comment: Solved. Have to set view_cache property in facotries.yml.

Comment: Post an answer with your solution and accept it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

factories.yml

```
view_cache:
  class: sfFileCache
  param:
    automatic_cleaning_factor: 0
    cache_dir:                 %SF_TEMPLATE_CACHE_DIR%
    lifetime:                  86400
    prefix:                    %SF_APP_DIR%/template
```